# Store the Controllers name and Actions Name into my Custom Tables that I Add them into Identity in CodeFirst Asp.Net MVC Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, code-first

Seniors, 
I'm using ASP.NET Identity on my ASP.Net web application and I Add my custom Tables(with their relations) to Identity on my **CodeFirst ASP.Net MVC Project**.when I Run Project for the first time,the databace is created automatically with the custom tables and relations between them in SqlServer. 
**Custom Tables :**

1. MvcControllers
2. ActionsTbls
3. GroupsTbls
4. AspNetUser_Action
5. AspNetUser_Group
6. Action_Group

   - This is The Diagram of my Database Image :
      [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jgtf.jpg)

For Creating Custom tables,I Add Some Codes to IdentityModels.cs. 
**IdentityModels.cs :**

```
namespace Admin_Base_SN.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public virtual AspNetUser_Action AspNetUser_Action { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser_Group AspNetUser_Group { get; set; }

    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {


        public DbSet<MvcController> MvcController { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ActionsTbls> ActionsTbls { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AspNetUser_Action> AspNetUser_Actions { get; set; }

        public DbSet<GroupsTbl> GroupsTbls { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Action_Group> Action_Groups { get; set; }

        public DbSet<AspNetUser_Group> AspNetUser_Groups { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // one-to-zero or one relationship between ApplicationUser and Customer
            // UserId column in Customers table will be foreign key
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOptional(m => m.AspNetUser_Action)
                .WithRequired(m => m.ApplicationUser)
                .Map(p => p.MapKey("AspNetUser_Id"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOptional(m => m.AspNetUser_Group)
                .WithRequired(m => m.ApplicationUser)
                .Map(p => p.MapKey("AspNetUser_Id"));

        }

    }
}
```

What I want  
At first,I want to save All the Controllers Names and Actions Names of Project into separated Lists,then insert them into MvcController Table & ActionsTbl Table.This process should be done  automatically when I Run Project for the first time.I mean When the Database is Created, the Lists inert to their tables automatically.

- I think it's better to Add a New Custom Function to the Identity for inserting Lists to the Tables.

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my problem.

Comment: The database is a file and once you put the data into the database it is saved permanently in the file.  All you need to do is to connect to the database.

Comment: Show me in Code ,plz.

Comment: This idea has been implemented here: https://github.com/mo-esmp/DynamicRoleBasedAccess

Comment: Where is the connection string?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Admin_Base_SN_DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If desired types are **Controller** and **ActionResult** (without web api), then
you may get controllers and actions by using reflection

```
        var controllers = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(*any type in assembly*))
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller)))
            .ToList();

        var result = controllers
            .Select(type => new
            {
                ControllerType = type,
                Actions = type.GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.ReturnType == typeof(ActionResult) || m.ReturnType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ActionResult))).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
```

Since you're using EF you can put all necessary logic into [Seed Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)
and enable [Automatic Migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx)